# Swift HStack View not conforming to protocol 'View'

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have built this code

```
struct StarDifficultyView: View {

var numberOfStarsToShow: Int
var numberOfTotalStarsToShow: Int = 5

var body: some View {
    HStack{
        var numberLeftToShow = numberOfStarsToShow
        ForEach(1..<numberOfTotalStarsToShow+1){_ in
            if(numberLeftToShow > 0){
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
                numberLeftToShow -= 1
            }else{
                Image(systemName: "star.fille")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

It gives me an error on the line `if(numberLeftToShow > 0){` saying "Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'"

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: The `ForEach` is not a operator, it is view container with view builder closure, you cannot do `numberLeftToShow -= 1` within view builder. Take SwiftUI some tutorial.

Comment: Are there any code suggestions you could make. I have done tutorials. this is what I have learnt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Explaining the issue:

You should not add expressions inside the view builder. So `numberLeftToShow -= 1` will throw and error because it returns a `void` ('aka' type()) and this does not conform to `View`! that is the exact reason for the compiler!

#### Note 1

Don't use SwiftUI like the UIKit! SwiftUI views may execute over time on any state change and should not be used for calculating anything in this way

#### Note 2

You can convert `1..<numberOfTotalStarsToShow+1` to a closed range like `1...numberOfTotalStarsToShow` (Although you don't need it at all for this question)

#### Note 3

Try not to use branch and convert your if/else code to something like:

```
Image(systemName: numberLeftToShow > 0 ? "star.fill" : "star.fille")
    .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
```

#### Note 4:

The lower bound of a range can not be less than the upper range, but you can iterate over a reversed range like:

```
(1...numberOfTotalStarsToShow).reversed()
```

#### Note 5:

try using a single source of truth like the forEach parameter itself!

#### Note 6:

Swift can infer the type and you don't need to pass it again:
so change `Color.yellow` to `.yellow`

#### Final Result:

Here is the code reviewed answer (based on the answer you have provided yourself):

```
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(1...numberOfTotalStarsToShow, id:\.self) { i in
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(i > numberOfStarsToShow ? .gray : .yellow)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. this really helped. also, really liked your proper explanation

Answer (score 3):

Don't throw away the closure parameter for the `ForEach`!

```
var body: some View {
    HStack{
        ForEach(0..<numberOfTotalStarsToShow){ i in // don't ignore the "i" here by writing "_"

            // "i" will be different in each "iteration"
            // use that to figure out which image to show
            if(i < numberOfStarsToShow){
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "star")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't actually think of this, which is quite silly of me. Thanks